# how to get the return value of a view function in flask with XMLHttpRequest from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask, xmlhttprequest

I cannot retrieve the transcript value with javascript using XMLHttpRequest,
what's wrong with my code?
everything works fine but i need the return value of transcript variable which is a long text

```
@app.route("/transcribe", methods=['POST'])
def transcribe():
        transcript = ""
        videos = glob.glob("static/uploads/video/*")
        ToEmptyDir()
        for video in videos:
            prs = parse_seconde(video)
            transcript = cut_video(prs, video).lstrip()
            insertToFile(video.split("\\")[1].split(".")[0], transcript)
        txtFile = glob.glob(os.getcwd() + "/*.txt")
        return transcript
```

index.html :

```
<button type="button" id="transcribe" onclick="loadTranscribeFile()"> Transcribe </button>
<script>
     function loadTranscribeFile(callback) {
             var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
             req.open('POST', '/transcribe', true);
             req.responseType = 'json';
             req.send("textTranscribed=" + document.getElementById('textTranscribed').value);
     }
</script>
```

Comment: it's sad to see that people have fun putting us -1 while I myself am stuck for hours looking and trying but it's in vain: /

Comment: you need to have the call back function for response that you'll get from the call

Comment: can you give me an example to do this? @Abhishek

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
req.onreadystatechange = function(res){
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
        var t = JSON.parse(req.responseText)
        console.log(t);
        }
}
```

Comment: call this before `req.send()`